# What is remote port forwarding command `ssh -R 80:localhost:8080 nokey@localhost.run` equivalent to in Paramiko?

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, portforwarding

`ssh -R 80:localhost:8080 nokey@localhost.run` is equivalent to what in Paramiko?
I search a lot but no success ...
Code I tried

```
import paramiko

command = "df"

# Update the next three lines with your
# server's information

username = "localhost:9876"
host = "nokey@localhost.run"

client = paramiko.client.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(host,port=80, username=username)
_stdin, _stdout,_stderr = client.exec_command("df")
print(stdout.read().decode())
client.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

A partial equivalent is [`Transport.request_port_forward`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/transport.html#paramiko.transport.Transport.request_port_forward).

But that will only setup the server-side part of the forwarding. The local-side implementation that will establish the local connection from the SSH client (Paramiko) to the local server is up to you.

An example how to implement it is given in [`demos/rforward.py`](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/main/demos/rforward.py).

An equivalent of your command will be:

```
python3 rforward.py -u nokey -p 80 -r 127.0.0.1:8080 localhost.run
```

Note that the `rforward.py` script does not start a shell. It just does the forwarding. So it's actually an equivalent of `ssh` with [`-N` switch](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#N).

If you need both forwarding and shell, you will need to modify the script to additionally do [`SSHClient.invoke_shell`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.invoke_shell) like [`demos/demo.py`](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/main/demos/demo.py) do.