# SSH Remote Port Forwarding using Python

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I am trying to expose a local port on my laptop to be accessed by everyone through Python, this python script will be run by someone without ssh installed (Windows). I try to use `paramiko` module but it only allow me to do Local port forwarding.

```py
import paramiko, sys
from forward import forward_tunnel

remote_host = "localhost"
remote_port = 3001
local_port  = 3000
ssh_host    = SERVER_IP
ssh_port    = 22

user     = "root"
password = "pAss@123A"

transport = paramiko.Transport((ssh_host, ssh_port))
transport.connect(hostkey  = None,
            username = user,
            password = password,
            pkey     = None)

try:
    forward_tunnel(local_port, remote_host, remote_port, transport)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('Port forwarding stopped.')
    sys.exit(0)
```

But I want to do remote port forwarding, like I want to replicate the following ssh command.

```bash
ssh -R 0.0.0.0:3001:127.0.0.1:3000 -N root@SERVER_IP
```

Comment: Paramiko provides [a remote port forward demo](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/main/demos/rforward.py); that's probably where you should start.

Comment: how did I miss this! thanks a lot.

Comment: See also [What is remote port forwarding command `ssh -R 80:localhost:8080 nokey@localhost.run` equivalent to in Paramiko?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73095788/850848).